# Ограничения Visual c# Express по работе с БД

Tags: c#, ide

Добрый день! Подскажите пожалуйста, какие у Visual c# Express есть ограничения по работе с базами данных.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никаких. Это полноценная версия.

Comment: А по сети приложение БД работать сможет? (т.е. БД на сервере на удаленном компьютере)?